# AS3 Curious structure question

Tags: actionscript-3, oop, structure

I'm (I think) quite good at structuring my application classes and packages, but lately I've been weighing something up that I could use some advice on:

Classes that contain only static constants, like this:

```
package //?
{
    public class Elements
    {
        public static const FIRE:String = "fire";
        public static const WATER:String = "water";
    }
}
```

Which are obviously used in situations like this:

```
var myElement:String = Elements.FIRE;
```

I've always placed these classes in packages that contain other classes which make the most use of them. For example, this class might be in `game.mobiles` because this package contains classes for mobiles (Player, enemies, etc) which make the most use of `Elements`; they have resistances and damage that can be elemental.

This seems odd to me though, because `Elements` really doesn't have anything to do with Mobiles (as it's not a Mobile or technically even related to a Mobile).

I've started to wonder if I should put all of my classes like the above into a generic package such as `game.statics`, though this seems just as messy from some points of view.

What should I look at doing here to have an as clean and understandable structure possible when it comes to these little classes?

Comment: Weapons and armour will have elemental properties, but these would be packaged under game.items.equipment.(weapons/armour). This is a good example of where the Elements class will be needed a lot as well - but placing it within game.items seems even more odd.

Comment: Marty, I have done it as you have in most cases. Do you have weapons/armor classes that have elemental attributes ? If you are just considering a weapon/armor as a part of the Player and Enemy classes ,that is kind of creating the situation where they are directly dependent on Elements. They ARE a part of your mobiles by your definition and coupled to them.

Comment: sorry deleted the comment to add to it. If weapons/armor are handled in their own classes, mobiles don't need to know it exists. I've been down this road more than a few times :) It bothers me as well. But it makes more sense as an item attribute, than a mobile attribute. It really depends on how far you want to go:)

Comment: Will there be items other than equipment that have elemental effects ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the base class for mobiles and the base class for items will both be making heavy use of Elements. Are you saying that because armour and weapons have damage and defence based on an element that the Mobiles class shouldn't need to make much use of Elements itself?

Comment: Without knowing your game design. What about elements is affecting your mobile ?  If a weapon and armor have elemental attributes, damage gets calculated based on those. Maybe all your mobile needs to know is what it's damage is. Not how or why.

Comment: True, but think how heavily I'll be using Elements.X throughout the base class for mobiles. e.g. the AI for some enemies might tweak their tactics based on your resistances. if(target.resistances[Elements.FIRE] > 0.6) dontUseFire();

Comment: well isn't it about comparing the weapons at your disposal to the armor of the target ? I guess what I am getting at is you can get very detailed. It's a matter of how detailed you want to get. I often end up in the situation you describe and say -- this doesn't make sense in some respect. But the point of it making sense -- might be far more work :)

Comment: also, isn't it projectiles that will end up with an elemental damage attributed to it ?

Comment: Could be anything. Like I said, these constants will be used throughout the game - I was just looking to categorize this better than "wherever it's needed most".

Comment: so if you followed what I was saying, a player wouldn't need to know about an element. You could even take a step further out and have the player have a weapons system, with it's function being making these decisions. Now the player class doesn't even need to know about a specific weapon. Your Player might just say --- hey weapons system, here's my target. Whats' the best option you got ?

Comment: True, but at some point a Mobile will need to make use of this class. The Element class doesn't do anything, it just holds strings in a neater way. I could easily ditch the Elements class and just use "fire" etc, just doesn't look nice.

Comment: OOP is about removing dependency/coupling so that code is more portable. How far you go, is up to you. time/effort go into that equation. You could remove the need for your player to even know what an element is.  I know exactly what you mean about "doesn't look nice" though. With games more than applications, I've found myself drawing the line quicker - unless you expect to expand the game over time or are focusing on using code in other projects as well. So, I've found a way to live in harmony with the classes like Elements being stragglers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your existing method is correct as it is the most logical. Typically you don't see (in common architectures) classes that contain ONLY static/constant variables. You'd typically see them bundled with a class where the functionality that most utilizes these statics exists. For example, any of the Events classes in AS3. You'd see the static const MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN etc bundled in with the actual event class (MouseEvent). I think separating them into a package that purely exists to store statics would be less logical, although it wouldn't necessarily be wrong. Anyway if you were to follow the example of something established, I'd look to the AS3 language itself as an example and in that example we can see that the flash core team seems to assemble classes into packages with the highest level of association. I think perhaps your doubt in this is arising because you have a class composed purely of constants and no functionality or inheritance that couples or links the class(es) explicitly to anything else.

Comment: This makes sense, though even AS3 runs into my situation. Have a look at the StageScaleMode class - which is packaged in flash.display. This is logical to me because it has a strong relation to the display, and is only needed for setting the scaleMode property on Stage which is also packaged under flash.display. The thing with my example is Elements could be referenced throughout the entire game (to display info in your character sheet e.g. fireResist.text = player.resistances[Elements.FIRE]; and so on.

Comment: Yeah I understand the dilemma, it is a bit of an odd-ball class. Usually when I see a class like this in other works they tend to be put into a namespace like "mydomain.core.XXX." I dunno like I said I don't think placing it in it's own package/namespace would necessarily be wrong. Perhaps someone else might have a little more insight.

Comment: Sounds about as realistic as I can get, really. Thanks for backing my current structure - I think I'll have to stick with this.

Answer (score 0):

I guess if I have a lot of constants that are pertinent to a particular task, but may be needed by more than one class (say, the value for gravity in a game), I'll put them in a definition class like that. I dislike functional classes referencing each other simply for constant values (too much coupling).

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what you mean by your last sentence? "I dislike function..."

Comment: Well, if Class A is referencing a constant in Class B, then any SWF that Class A gets used in also needs a copy of Class B in it, which then requires all the classes that Class B references to be there... it can add up in situations where small file size is desirable. If both classes A and B are referencing constants in a simple Class C, then there's no cascade of additional class linking when either A or B is used by itself in a file.